# Compare 2 Excel files and output an Excel file with differences

Tags: python, excel, compare

Assume for simplicity that the data files look like this, sorted on ID:

```
ID  | Data1  | Data2  | Data3   | Data4
199 |  Tim   |   55   |  work  |  $55
345 |  Joe   |   45   |  work  |  $34
356 |  Sam   |   23   |  uni   |  $12
```

Each file has more than 100,000 rows and about 50 columns.
I want to compare a 2nd file with the first for new records (new ID ), edits (IDs match but columns 2 or 4 have changed (Data1 and Data3), and Deletes (ID in first file does not exist in the 2nd file).

Output is to appear in an Excel file with the first column containing D, E or N (for Delete, Edit and New), and the rest of the columns being the same as the columns in the files being compared.

For new records the full new record is to appear in the output file.
For Edits both the records are to appear in the output file, but only those fields that have changed are to appear.
For deleted records the full old record is to appear in the output file.

I would also like the following output to the screen as the files are being processed:

```
Deletes: D: 199, Tim
Edits:   E: 345, Joe -> John
         E: 345, work -> xxx
New:     N: 999, Ami
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please read [How To ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would read the excel files in pandas, do an outer join on `ID` and compare the columns to see which records have changed

Comment: I am an absolute beginner, so could you provide some code for this please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read some of the [excellent](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/Index.ipynb) [introductions](http://pbpython.com/archives.html) to pandas to understand how and why this works and to adapt it to your specific needs

## Reading the excel-files

[`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)

```
import pandas as pd

filename1 = 'filename1.xlsx'
filename2 = 'filename2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(filename1, index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename2, index_col=0)
```

df1 and df2 should be `pandas.DataFrame`s with `ID` as `index` and the first row as `columns` or headers

## Merging the files

[`pandas.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', sort=False, indicator=True)
```

## Selecting the changes

```
id_new = df_merged.index[df_merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'] 
id_deleted = df_merged.index[df_merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'] 
id_changed_data1 = df_merged.index[(df_merged['_merge'] == 'both') & (df_merged['Data1_x'] != df_merged['Data1_y'])]
id_changed_data3 = df_merged.index[(df_merged['_merge'] == 'both') & (df_merged['Data3_x'] != df_merged['Data3_y'])]
```

This gives you lists (or an `Index` rather) of the changes, which you can format as you want

Comment: Thanks @Maarten. Below is the code I have now.

import pandas as pd

f1 = 'E0.xlsx'
f2 = 'E1.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(f1, index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(f2, index_col=0)

df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, ... as you wrote

id_new     = df_merged.index[df_merged['_merge'] == 'right_only'] 
id_deleted = df_merged.index[df_merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'] 

id_changed_name    = df_merged.index[(df_merged['_merge'] == 'both') & (df_merged['Name_x'   ] != df_merged['Name_y'   ])]

I want to save the Deleted, New and Changed  records to separate Excel files.

Comment: comments are not good at displaying code. You could edit your answer and include qwhat you have so far

Comment: Hi Maarten, is there a simple way to get just the changes between the files, ie the row index matches, but one or more column entries are different. The tables I'd be using would have ~200 columns.

Comment: @Cian, I don't 100% understand your question. Check on SO, and if there is no previous similar question, ask a new one, preferably with some sample in- and output

Comment: Hi Maarten, I posted a fresh question here (referencing your above solution) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925360/get-differences-between-two-excel-files